# OPENROWSET with Excel file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel, oledb, openrowset

I want to execute simple statement:

```
SELECT * FROM 
OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0','Text;Database=C:\Temp\;','SELECT * FROM [test.csv]')
```

And suddenly I get this message today morning:

```
Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
OLE DB provider 'MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.
```

It was working till today morning!

Here is my server specs:
Windows 2008 R2 64 bit
SQL Server 2008 64 bit

I've installed AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe.

Sql Server is running under LocalService account. 
I've set Everyone to have FullControl permission to "C:\Temp" as well as "C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local".

Is there anything I missed? I'm really confused...

Edited:
I've also executed these statements:

```
sp_configure ‘show advanced options’, 1;
 GO
 RECONFIGURE;
 GO
 sp_configure ‘Ad Hoc Distributed Queries’, 1;
 GO
 RECONFIGURE;
 GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N’Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0′, N’AllowInProcess’, 1
 GO
 EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N’Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0′, N’DynamicParameters’, 1
 GO
```

I've also tested `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` with administrator account:

```
SELECT * FROM  
OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=C:\Temp\;','SELECT * FROM [test.csv]')
```

There is another error:

```
OLE DB provider "MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

**Finally I found it:
I ran ProcMon and I saw that Sql Server wants to access to F:\Windows Temp\ and the folder does not exist! I created the folder and the issue is solved. But, I never had such a folder!!!**

Comment: Are you using `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` or `JET.OLEDB.4.0`? On x64 version of the server you'll need to use `ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

Comment: I'm using ACE.OLEDB.12.0 and it was working for a year before. Is there any Windows Update which cause this issue? I just tried JET.OLEDB.4.0 to test written in some blogs.

Comment: Do you start SQL Server service under user account security context?

Comment: It's running under Local Service account.

Comment: I got the exact same error reading CSV files until setting permissions on TEMP folder of the user account SQL Server runs under. More info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/07/23/ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-linked-server-null-returned-message-unspecified-error.aspx

Comment: I've set Full Control for Everyone to the folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finally I found it: I ran ProcMon and I saw that SQL Server wants to access to `F:\Windows Temp\` and the folder does not exist! I created the folder and the issue is solved. But, I never had such a folder!!!**