# OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I want to import data from Excel to SQL Server using queries, not by using a wizard. I tried this query:

```
Select * INTO g FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\new.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [newSheet$]');
```

But, I am getting this error:

> Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
>   OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.

So I searched on Google, and I got answers like:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Even after reconfiguring it is showing me the same error...

Comment: This may not be a solution but you seem to have a mismatch in your connection string.  For `.xlsx` files with `Excel 12.0` you should be using `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.  `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` would be specified with `Excel 8.0` but that only supports `.xls` files from Excel 97-2003.

Comment: @agentnega I tried changing excel file to .xls format after that also am getting same error

Comment: Oops this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605371/error-in-query-when-trying-to-import-excel-file-to-sql?rq=1 which is also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687631/openrowset-with-excel-file.  See those questions for possible answers.

Comment: `EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'AllowInProcess'   , 1;
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'DynamicParameters', 1;`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5b29496-d6a1-4ecf-b1a4-5550d80b84b6/microsoftjetoledb40-32bit-and-64bit?forum=adodotnetdataproviders),:

> Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not supported for 64-bit OS

Assuming you are running SQL Server 64-bit, you likely need the **64-bit [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255)**.

And be aware that there is a minor wrinkle when trying to install the software if the other version is already installed.  In this case install the second version from the command line using the **/passive** switch.  According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/57aee87f-a2e0-4804-a452-7c69f1d32957/how-i-can-install-access-database-engine-without-uninstalling-microsoft-office?forum=exceldev):

> Launching the install of a Microsoft ACE OLEDB Provider on a machine with an Office install other than the current one (e.g. 32 on 64) will cause the install to fail. To have it run properly you need to launch it from a command line with the **“/passive”** argument specified.

That is talking about an existing Office install but the same applies to coexisting database engine installations.

EDIT:  Also make sure to use "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" not "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for the provider string.  (Props to @Rumi)

Comment: You have full and detailed instructions here http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-linked-servers.htm

Comment: This works but you have to change  'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'  to 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'. Maybe you should put this inside the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use SQL like below:

```
  SELECT * into temptable FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\new.xlsx','select * from [sheet1$]')
```