# Export data from SQL Server to MS Access

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ms-access-2003

I need to write a stored procedure which reads data from SQL Server and writes it into a MS Access 2003 table. I tried the following but it is not working:

```
Insert into OpenRowSet
('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',      
'D:\BEMF_LOAN_RECOVERY.mdb';  
''; -- User ID
'', -- Password
'Select * from access_tbl_name') 
    Select * 
    from sql_server_tbl_name
```

Error mesage

> Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Do you realise that the `D:` drive in question will be the one on the SQL Server, not on your local PC, assuming that they're different?

Comment: @MattGibson both SQL SERVER and file.mdb are on same machine.

Comment: That's not an error message I've seen before. (Can you pull the data from the Access side rather than trying to push it in from SQL Server? Most times I've seen Access grabbing SQL Server data it's just been done inside Access through a simple linked table...) Also, although it's about Excel, [this question may be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032222/ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-cannot-be-used-for-distributed-queries).

Comment: I am not an expert all i need to write a stored procedure which can export data to MS Access table, please help

Comment: @MattGibson i was following that and that was working for me to write into excel but I need to write into Access table, for which i have no clue how to do it.

Comment: I'm just wondering if you really do need to do that. In Access itself, you can create a linked table to a SQL Server table or view, and that would be the normal way to pull data from SQL Server to Access, plus it means that your data will always be up-to-date.

Comment: Have you tried using `access_tbl_name` instead of `'Select * from access_tbl_name'` as the last parameter of `OpenRowSet` ?

Comment: @Andre451 Yes but still same result

Comment: Did you follow the link given by Matt? The 32-vs-64-bit issue sounds applicable to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' is enabled on your SQL Server?

> By default, SQL Server does not allow ad hoc distributed queries using
>   OPENROWSET and OPENDATASOURCE. When this option is set to 1, SQL
>   Server allows ad hoc access. When this option is not set or is set to
>   0, SQL Server does not allow ad hoc access.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569.aspx