# How to Extract the Query result to directly to .XLSx File

Tags: sql-server

Could you please let me know how to Extract Query result to Excel sheet in SQL server,

My query is batch Job, so I need to keep all my query result in Excel sheet, Later I will do FTP.

Please suggest me is there any way to do in SQL Server.

Note :- Not using Result to File in Management studio, I need to know using any scripts in Sql

Comment: There is no way I know of directly from a SQL script.  The two most common ways to do this is creating a SSIS package created with SQL Server Data Tools or using a Powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
First Enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Export Result Query to Excel File

```
DECLARE @STR_QUERY AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @FILE_ATT_PATH NVARCHAR(50) ='D:\MYEXCEL'+REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),113),':','')+'.XLS';

SET @STR_QUERY = 
N'INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'', ''Excel 8.0;Database='+ @FILE_ATT_PATH +';'',''SELECT CusSName FROM [Sheet1$]'')
SELECT CusSName FROM [dbo].[MasterCustomer]'

EXEC sp_executesql @STR_QUERY
```

Comment: Dear Sir, Thanks for your response, I am getting an error message :- Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.

Comment: First, You run Enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries before run Export Result Query to Excel File already?

Comment: I did that Sir, but still no output, am getting same error message, Kindly help me

Comment: Try to setup Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable in your database server, Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032222/ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-cannot-be-used-for-distributed-queries [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032222/ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-cannot-be-used-for-distributed-queries)